# Composer detected issues in your platform: Your composer dependencies require a PHP version ">=8.1.0"

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, cpanel

On live CPanel, i uploaded a laravel project of version ^8.75 which is throwing this error.

I tried to update CPanel php version from MultiPHP Manager but it is still not working, composer install or composer update command also not working. has anyone also faced the same issue?

Comment: run this command composer update --ignore-platform-reqs

Comment: "throwing this error" - what does that mean? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?